# NetworkStreamですぐにRead可能なデータがあるかどうかを調べるには？

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, socket

お世話になっております。
C#にて、NetworkStreamクラスの仕様について質問があります。
Readをする前に、そのStreamにRead可能なデータが受信されているかどうかを判断する方法は
ありますでしょうか？

初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`NetworkStream.DataAvailable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable.aspx)プロパティを使用します。